# Mysql finding nearest overlap times considering exceptions

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find overlaping times between caterer and courier opened times
I have those tables in mysql
Table called caterer_openings

```
+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
| catererID | weekDay | openedFrom | openedTo |
+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 1         | 1       | 08:00      |  04:00   |
| 1         | 2       | 08:00      |  23:00   |
| 1         | 3       | 08:00      |  17:00   |
| 1         | 4       | 08:00      |  17:00   |
| 1         | 5       | 09:00      |  18:00   |
| 1         | 6       | 09:00      |  18:00   |
| 1         | 7       | 09:00      |  18:00   |
+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Then i have table caterer_openings_exceptions, where is described exceptions.

```
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------+
| catererID | exceptionDate | openedFrom | openedTo |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------+
| 1         | 2016-06-20    | 08:30      |  01:30   |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------+
```

Table called courier_openings, that means courier will start delivering caterer foods at those times in weekday

```
+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
| courierID | weekDay | openedFrom | openedTo |
+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
| 1         | 1       | 10:00      |  01:00   |
| 1         | 2       | 10:00      |  18:00   |
| 1         | 3       | 10:00      |  17:00   |
| 1         | 4       | 10:00      |  17:00   |
| 1         | 5       | 10:00      |  23:00   |
| 1         | 6       | 10:00      |  23:00   |
| 1         | 7       | 10:00      |  23:00   |
+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Then i have table courier_openings_exceptions

```
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------+
| courierID | exceptionDate | openedFrom | openedTo |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------+
| 1         | 2016-06-19    | 10:30      |  19:00   |
+-----------+---------------+------------+----------+
```

I want to create sql query which finds nearest possible overlaped times

- For example current dateTime is **2016-06-19 11:00** and the next overlaping times should be **2016-06-19 10:30** - **2016-06-19 18:00**
- For example current dateTime is **2016-06-19 19:00** and the next overlaping times should be on monday **2016-06-20 10:00** - **2016-06-20 01:30**.
- If the _exceptions tables has no records then it should find overlaps only using _openigns table

I want to get these results via MySQL and PHP

Comment: Could you share some of the code you've already made with us? Where do you run into difficulties?

Comment: Thats the problem i haven't got the right query for me that works fast and give right results

Comment: A singular SQL query will definately not be the answer, you really have to use PHP and add only a little bit of SQL to get the data from your database. I think you have to try harder, we're not here to do your job.

Comment: So, ignoring exceptions and specific dates, can you write a query that simply identifies day by day overlaps?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware A singular query (and a bit of PHP) seems like a valid answer to me !

Comment: Yes, it can probably be done, but at the expense of great complexity and inflexibility. Better import data in PHP, and work at the problem there. First you need to convert weekdays to future real dates, find the overlap on the same dates, while keeping an eye on the exceptions. In PHP that's not overly complex.

Comment: Also, consider amending your design, so that you have one table for businesses, and another for business openings.

Comment: I didnt say that it should be singular query, i can use multiple qureries as well

Comment: Just divide and conquer. You should be able to do this entirely on your own. It that means not a stellar way, just do it anyway. Otherwise it is the classic case of "here is my toughest part of my system, here someone just do it for me"

Comment: Good point, i'll give it a try, actually now i have a solution but its so c**p i cant post it to stack :)

Comment: There, an upvote for trying (that is the research part of it), plus the question is interesting.